# Wondering how to switch these two divs?

Tags: html, css

I've put wrapped them in divs and put `inline-block` on both of them to have them side by side and I was wondering how I could switch it so that the right is on the left?

[image]

```css
.contactInformation {
    background-color: $Ice;
    height: 100vh;
    .contactInfo {
        border: 2px solid red;
        width: 25%;
        display: inline-block;
        p {
            line-height: 15px;
        }
        h4 {
            font-size: 1.625;
            letter-spacing: 1.1px;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }
        i {
            padding: 0 10px;
        }
    }
}













.container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 50px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.right-side {
    width: 50%;
    background: $White;
    .top {
        width: 600px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        input {
            width: 45%;
            font-size: 20px;
            padding: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
    }
    textarea {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 100px;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        resize: none;
    }
    .button {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2px auto;
    }
}
```

```html
    <main class="contact contactInformation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="right-side">
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="top">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <textarea name="name" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="contactInfo">
            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-f"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
            <i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp"></i>
            <h4>INFO@EMAIL.COM</h4>
            <p>123 - 456 - 7890</p>
            <p>123 Queen Street West, Unit 10</p>
            <p>Toronto, Ontario</p>
            <P>M5V2D5</P>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Show your code please. HTML and CSS.

Comment: Can you provide some Code?

Comment: sorry I've posted the code now!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using flexbox with the order command:

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.wrapper .wrapper__child1 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    order: 2;
    background: red;
}

.wrapper .wrapper__child2 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    order: 1;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper__child1"></div>
    <div class="wrapper__child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex and then set flex-direction to `reverse-row`. so your CSS would be:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: reverse-row;
}
```